# date filtering in django with __gte does not add apostrophe

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

when filtering using `__gte` on `models.DateTimeField` the printed query doesn't wrap the searched date with an apostrophe `'` this may lead to undesired results in postgres database:

```
WHERE ("appname_tablename"."creation_date" >= 2021-06-27 11:08:29.311284+00:00 AND "appname_tablename"."node_id" = 111)
```

switching to a raw query set which requires further processing since the result needs to go though aggregation and so on,
any ideas?

Comment: Is there an error or you're just being cautious? I'm pretty sure it won't be a problem if you're using django's ORM. If there's a problem, please add the error message you get.

Comment: no error, and the query actually works but it won't pass code review and go into production

Comment: How did you get the raw query? I've just checked and it's indeed wrapped into `'` for me

Comment: filter_query = f'select * FROM "appname_tablename" \
+        WHERE ("appname_tablename"."creation_date" >= \
+        to_date(\'{start_time}\', \'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS\') \
+        AND "appname_tablename"."node_id" = {node.pk})'

Comment: i'm pretty sure it's not the desired behavior i'll submit a bug report